# Count new email

Tags: php, codeigniter, count, message, badge

I have one problem. This code count very well a new message but the replay message is not showing the number.
Ex: 10 messages ( 6 new message + 4 replay messages)
Now is showing 6 message. 
Should show 10 message.
The table is message with columns:

> message_id | message_thread_code | message | sender | timestamp |
>   read_status

The second table is message_thread with columns:

> message_thread_id | message_thread_code | sender | reciever |
>   last_message_timestamp

```
<!-- message number apper count per user // START -->               
<?php
$current_user = $this->session->userdata('login_type') . '-' . $this->session->userdata('login_user_id');
$this->db->where('message_thread.reciever', $current_user);
$this->db->where('message.read_status', 0);
$this->db->from('message_thread');
$this->db->join('message', 'message.message_thread_code = message_thread.message_thread_code');
$unread_message_number = $this->db->count_all_results();
?> 
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/message">  
<i class="entypo-mail"></i>
Casuta mesaje
<span class="badge badge-secondary"><?php echo $unread_message_number; ?></span>
<!-- message number apper count per user // FINISH -->  

The controller:

function count_unread_message_of_thread($message_thread_code) {
    $unread_message_counter = 0;
    $current_user = $this->session->userdata('login_type') . '-' . $this->session->userdata('login_user_id');
    $messages = $this->db->get_where('message', array('message_thread_code' => $message_thread_code))->result_array();
    foreach ($messages as $row) {
        if ($row['sender'] != $current_user && $row['read_status'] == '0')
            $unread_message_counter++;
    }
    return $unread_message_counter;
}
```

Comment: Tip you should have your database stuff in a model function then load  on to controller then to view. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#what-is-a-model

Comment: I add the controller

Comment: im sorry but i cant catch your question, can u more explain what your problem?

Comment: The current code count all new message from current user. If i replay a message to another user... the count from receiver-user don't count this replay message.